# Remove item from array with click function

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a Todo react app, where when you click on checkbox, the selected item is stored in an array, and displayed in a separate div where there is cross icon. I wanted to remove the displayed item in my second div when clicked on cross icon.

Below is my code:

```
const [list1, setList1] = useState([]);

const pushHandler1 = (data) => {
    let newArr = [];
    if (!list1.includes(data)) {
        newArr = [...list1, data];
        setList1(newArr)
        console.log("put: ", newArr);
    }
    else {
        newArr = list1.filter((id) => id !== data);
        setList1(newArr)
        console.log("pull", newArr);
    }
}

<div id="listBox1">
    <Checkbox
        defaultChecked={false}
        color="primary"
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'secondary checkbox' }}
        onChange={(e) => pushHandler1(e.target.name)} name="Language1"
    />
    <label>Language1</label>
</div>

<div id="listBox2">
    {
        list1.length > 0 &&
        <div className='checkList'>
            {
                list1 && list1.length > 0 &&
                list1.map((ele, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index} className="listItemDiv">
                            <p>{ele}</p>
                            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" onClick={(e) => pushHandler1(e.target.name)} name="Language1"></i>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

But instead of deleting this item, it creates a new empty div in my second Div. I am new to JavaScript and react js and not able to figure what I am doing wrong.

**NOTE**
Thank you for the answer:

changing the onClick in this way `onClick={(e) => pushHandler1(ele)}` helped me in solving the issue.

But now there is one more issue. When I cancel the selected item, my checkbox is still checked(true). So if now I uncheck it, it displays the unchecked item in my second div. Is there a way to also uncheck the checkbox, when cancelling the selected item?

Answer (score 0):

`i` elements don't have a `name` attribute, and so they don't have the `name` reflected property that `input` and other elements have.

Since you're already creating a function for the click handler, you don't need to put an attribute on the `i`, just put the value directly in the handler:

```
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" onClick={(e) => pushHandler1("Language1")}></i>
```

That said, hardcoding the value doesn't look right. It seems like that should be `ele`, not `"Language1"`:

```
<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" onClick={(e) => pushHandler1(ele)}></i>
```

Comment: thank you, it's working now. Can you help me with one more issue. When you cancel the selected item, the checkbox is still true. So now if you uncheck the checkbox, it displays the unchecked item. Is there a way to also uncheck the checkbox when closing the selected Item?

Comment: @pratteekshaurya - I don't know what `Checkbox` component you're using, but typically they're controlled with a `checked` property.